# Responder Demographics Report via the Ads API

Tags: facebook-graph-api, ads, facebook-ads-api

Is there a way to retrieve Responder Demographics advertising reports, which break down performance by age, gender, and location, via the Ads API? If not, is this report type a planned API feature, and is there an ETA for when it might be implemented?